# Calling a member of an array in an if/else statement

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to write an if/else statement that says 'if the the random question chosen is the first in the array do this ....' etc for all the members of the array. However it is defaulting every question chosen as the first member of the array and carrying out that action. How can I get it to separate that?

```
if (choice == 1)
        {
            enum fields{ QUESTS, ANS_1, ANS_2, ANS_3, ANS_4, NUM_FIELDS };
            string QUEST[NUM_QUEST][NUM_FIELDS] =
            {
                { "What course is this?\n", "A)C++\n", "B)DID\n", "C)Intro to Game\n", "D)Yoga" },
                { "Who am I?\n", "A)Bill\n", "B)Nye\n", "C) 24601\n", "D)No one\n" },
                { "Are you actually reading this?\n", "A) Yes\n", "B)No\n", "C)Maybe\n", "D)Who wants to know?\n" },
                { "Will this program work?\n", "A)Of course it will!\n", "B)It might\n", "C)Are you kidding me?\n", "D)Gods only know." },
                { "Where would I rather be?\n", "A)Home\n", "B)Europe\n", "C)Anywhere but here\n", "D)All of the above\n" }
            };
            srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
            int randomQuest = (rand() % NUM_QUEST);
            string question = QUEST[randomQuest][QUESTS];
            cout << question;
            string printAns1 = QUEST[randomQuest][ANS_1];
            string printAns2 = QUEST[randomQuest][ANS_2];
            string printAns3 = QUEST[randomQuest][ANS_3];
            string printAns4 = QUEST[randomQuest][ANS_4];
            cout << printAns1;
            cout << printAns2;
            cout << printAns3;
            cout << printAns4;
            cout << "\nAnswer:";
            string answer;
            cin >> answer;
```

//PROBLEM IS HERE. KEEPS DEFAULTING TO THIS IF STATEMENT AND IGNORING THE REST SO THAT IT THINKS THE ANSWER IS ALWAYS A

```
            if (question == QUEST[randomQuest][0])
            {
                if (answer == "A")
                {
                    cout << "Correct. Proceed.";
                }

                else if (answer != "A")
                {
                    cout << "Failure. Leave. Or, you know, try again.";
                }
            }

            else if (question == QUEST[randomQuest][1])
            {
                if (answer == "C")
                {
                    cout << "Correct. Proceed.";
                }

                else if (answer != "C")
                {
                    cout << "Failure. Leave. Or, you know, try again.";
                }
            }

            else if (question == QUEST[randomQuest][2])
            {
                if (answer == "D")
                {
                    cout << "Correct. Proceed.";
                }

                else if (answer != "D")
                {
                    cout << "Failure. Leave. Or, you know, try again.";
                }
            }

            else if (question == QUEST[randomQuest][3])
            {
                if (answer == "C")
                {
                    cout << "Correct. Proceed.";
                }

                else if (answer != "C")
                {
                    cout << "Failure. Leave. Or, you know, try again.";
                }
            }

            else if (question == QUEST[randomQuest][4])
            {
                if (answer == "D")
                {
                    cout << "Correct. Proceed.";
                }

                else if (answer != "D")
                {
                    cout << "Failure. Leave. Or, you know, try again.";
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a step-through debugger?

Comment: Double check the array indexes you are using in your if statements. Think about exactly what value you'll be comparing `question` to.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the full source, so I just posted an example of how I would do this. Even thought it has a few more lines, its much more readable IMHO.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Question
{
    unsigned char answer;
    std::string title;
    std::vector<std::string> options;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Question> questions;

    // Define the questions
    Question questionOne;
    Question questionTwo;
    Question questionThree;
    Question questionFour;
    Question questionFive;

    questionOne.answer = 'c';
    questionOne.title = "What course is this?";
    questionOne.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionOne.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionOne.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionOne.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

    questionTwo.answer = 'a';
    questionTwo.title = "Who am I?";
    questionTwo.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionTwo.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionTwo.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionTwo.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

    questionThree.answer = 'b';
    questionThree.title = "Are you actually reading this?";
    questionThree.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionThree.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionThree.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionThree.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

    questionFour.answer = 'c';
    questionFour.title = "Will this program work?";
    questionFour.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionFour.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionFour.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionFour.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

    questionFive.answer = 'd';
    questionFive.title = "Where would I rather be?";
    questionFive.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionFive.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionFive.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    questionFive.options.push_back("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");

    // Save them
    questions.push_back(questionOne);
    questions.push_back(questionTwo);
    questions.push_back(questionThree);
    questions.push_back(questionFour);
    questions.push_back(questionFive);

    // Change to a random question accordingly
    for (auto& question : questions)
    {
        // Show question title
        std::cout << question.title << std::endl;

        // Show question options
        for (auto& option : question.options)
        {
            std::cout << option << std::endl;
        }

        // Get the user input accordingly
        unsigned char userInput = 0;

        // Validate user input
        if (userInput == question.answer)
        {
            std::cout << "Congratulations! Next question coming up..." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Wrong answer. Next question coming up..." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Answer with only code and without explanation is not considered a good answer.

Comment: @vishal Comments that disregards in any way the solution to this posts authors question is not considered even a kind of help either. He did not post the whole source, but even if he did, I'm not going to debug it for him to discover which bracket he forgot to include or any missed std::cin or whatsoever. Feel free to do it and help us all.